# Vuejs - Vue App build as component for other project's vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Im trying to build a vue app for other vue project's to be use as a component for the app vue router.
Here is my simple project structure for start,

```
|-- my-app
    |-- lib
        |-- my-app-component <-- folder copied from (my-app-component's dist)
    |-- App.vue
    |-- app.js
    |-- package.json



|-- my-app-component
    |-- dist
    |-- App.vue
    |-- app.js
    |-- package.json
```

Here is the idea and steps that I'm trying to implement,

1. build **my-app-component** as reusable component, the code at **my-app-component->app.js** is

```
import MyCustomElement from './App'

export {
   MyCustomElement
}
```

2. Copy the dist folder to **my-app**'s **lib** folder, this is just temporary solution, will be further improve using Lerna and yarn workspaces once I manage to solve the current problem
3. Import **my-app-component** from lib at **my-app**'s **lib**, the code at **my-app -> app.js** is,

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import MyAppComponent from '@lib/my-app-component'

const routes = [
  {
    name: 'MyAppComponent',
    path: '/',
    component: MyAppComponent
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: {
    App
  },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Based on this steps, I can't seem to import the component successfully.
Im building my component using **vue-cli-service build** command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to found the answer here...

https://itnext.io/create-a-vue-js-component-library-as-a-module-part-1-a1116e632751

I have been answering my own question these days, is stack overflow still alive?

Solution:

1. Build by

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name dummylib src/main.js
```

2. Add main at package.json

```
"main": "./dist/dummylib.common.js",
```

3. At main app, add component by

```
yarn add ../dummylib
```

4. Import and use the component

```
import DummyButton from 'dummylib'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    'dummy-button' : DummyButton
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I use compiled JS in another PHP project like a jQUery plugin?

Comment: Sorry, is it possible to dynamically import those components?

Comment: yes it should be possible, are you looking for vue component lazy loading?
https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-individual-vue-components-and-prefetching/